# Program to sync tracks' metadata from Traktor to Rekordbox

Tags: windows, gratis, music

I'm looking for a program that can:

- sync tracks' metadata from Traktor to Rekordbox. I'm essentially interested in converting Traktor cues to Rekordbox. Ideally, I wouldn't have to reanalyze the tracks again in Rekordbox. [Rekord Buddy](https://nextaudiolabs.com/whats-new-in-rekord-buddy-1-7/) does this on Mac OS but there is currently [no Windows version of Rekord Buddy](http://nextaudiolabs.com/answers/why-isnt-there-a-windows-version-of-rekord-buddy/).
- works on Windows 7 preferably (other Windows or Linux is OK too)

If possible:

- easy to use (e.g. no need to write some scripts)
- not major bugs (especially I don't want the cue conversion to be buggy)
- free